# Edit Unity shader that takes 2 vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-shaders

This a jelly shader from unity asset store yet I cant figure out how to make it always active as it requires 2 vector3 (_ModelOrigin and a __ImpactOrigin). Any ideas on how to edit it is always active?

Thats how I use it right now :

```
 modelRenderer.material.SetVector("_ModelOrigin", pos.transform.position);
 modelRenderer.material.SetVector("_ImpactOrigin", pos.transform.position += new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f));
```

*but when the gameobject mesh is too far it stops working*

I tried also to just use `transform.position` but when I move the gameobject the shader get new values so it becomes laggy for a second

Thanks

```
// Upgrade NOTE: upgraded instancing buffer 'Props' to new syntax.

Shader "Custom/JellyShader" {
    Properties{

        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _Transparency("Transparency", float) = 0.1

        _ControlTime("Time", float) = 0
        _ModelOrigin("Model Origin", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _ImpactOrigin("Impact Origin", Vector) = (-5,0,0,0)

         _Emission("Emission", float) = 0
         [HDR] _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)


        _Frequency("Frequency", Range(0, 1000)) = 10
        _Amplitude("Amplitude", Range(0, 5)) = 0.1
        _WaveFalloff("Wave Falloff", Range(1, 8)) = 4
        _MaxWaveDistortion("Max Wave Distortion", Range(0.1, 2.0)) = 1
        _ImpactSpeed("Impact Speed", Range(0, 10)) = 0.5
        _WaveSpeed("Wave Speed", Range(-10, 10)) = -5
    }
        SubShader{
            Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
            // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
            #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows addshadow vertex:vert alpha:fade

            // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            struct Input {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
            };

            half _Glossiness;
            half _Metallic;
            fixed4 _Color;

            fixed4 _EmissionColor;

            float _ControlTime;
            float4 _ModelOrigin;
            float4 _ImpactOrigin;
            float _Transparency;

            half _Frequency; //Base frequency for our waves.
            half _Amplitude; //Base amplitude for our waves.
            half _WaveFalloff; //How quickly our distortion should fall off given distance.
            half _MaxWaveDistortion; //Smaller number here will lead to larger distortion as the vertex approaches origin.
            half _ImpactSpeed; //How quickly our wave origin moves across the sphere.
            half _WaveSpeed; //Oscillation speed of an individual wave.


            // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
            // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
            UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
                // put more per-instance properties here
            UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

            void vert(inout appdata_base v) {
                float4 world_space_vertex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);

                float4 direction = normalize(_ModelOrigin - _ImpactOrigin);
                float4 origin = _ImpactOrigin + _ControlTime * _ImpactSpeed * direction;

                //Get the distance in world space from our vertex to the wave origin.
                float dist = distance(world_space_vertex, origin);

                //Adjust our distance to be non-linear.
                dist = pow(dist, _WaveFalloff);

                //Set the max amount a wave can be distorted based on distance.
                dist = max(dist, _MaxWaveDistortion);

                //Convert direction and _ImpactOrigin to model space for later trig magic.
                float4 l_ImpactOrigin = mul(unity_WorldToObject, _ImpactOrigin);
                float4 l_direction = mul(unity_WorldToObject, direction);

                //Magic
                float impactAxis = l_ImpactOrigin + dot((v.vertex - l_ImpactOrigin), l_direction);

                v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * sin(impactAxis * _Frequency + _ControlTime * _WaveSpeed) * _Amplitude * (1 / dist);
            }

            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
                // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
                o.Metallic = _Metallic;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
                o.Emission = c.rgb * tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).a * _EmissionColor;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
            FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to just remove them as properties and calculate the model pos based on the object to world transform and then use your offset to set the impact origin.

That way you don't need to set those parameters in c#, it should "just work".

```
// Upgrade NOTE: upgraded instancing buffer 'Props' to new syntax.

Shader "Custom/JellyShader" {
    Properties{

        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _Transparency("Transparency", float) = 0.1

        _ControlTime("Time", float) = 0

         _Emission("Emission", float) = 0
         [HDR] _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)


        _Frequency("Frequency", Range(0, 1000)) = 10
        _Amplitude("Amplitude", Range(0, 5)) = 0.1
        _WaveFalloff("Wave Falloff", Range(1, 8)) = 4
        _MaxWaveDistortion("Max Wave Distortion", Range(0.1, 2.0)) = 1
        _ImpactSpeed("Impact Speed", Range(0, 10)) = 0.5
        _WaveSpeed("Wave Speed", Range(-10, 10)) = -5
    }
        SubShader{
            Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
            // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
            #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows addshadow vertex:vert alpha:fade

            // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            struct Input {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
            };

            half _Glossiness;
            half _Metallic;
            fixed4 _Color;

            fixed4 _EmissionColor;

            float _ControlTime;
            float _Transparency;

            half _Frequency; //Base frequency for our waves.
            half _Amplitude; //Base amplitude for our waves.
            half _WaveFalloff; //How quickly our distortion should fall off given distance.
            half _MaxWaveDistortion; //Smaller number here will lead to larger distortion as the vertex approaches origin.
            half _ImpactSpeed; //How quickly our wave origin moves across the sphere.
            half _WaveSpeed; //Oscillation speed of an individual wave.


            // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
            // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
            UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
                // put more per-instance properties here
            UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

            void vert(inout appdata_base v) {
                float4 world_space_vertex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
 
                // hardcoded stuff:
                float4 _ModelOrigin = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, float4(0,0,0,1));
                float4 _ImpactOffset = float4(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0);
                float4 _ImpactOrigin = _ModelOrigin + _ImpactOffset;

                float4 direction = normalize(_ModelOrigin - _ImpactOrigin);
                float4 origin = _ImpactOrigin + _ControlTime * _ImpactSpeed * direction;

                //Get the distance in world space from our vertex to the wave origin.
                float dist = distance(world_space_vertex, origin);

                //Adjust our distance to be non-linear.
                dist = pow(dist, _WaveFalloff);

                //Set the max amount a wave can be distorted based on distance.
                dist = max(dist, _MaxWaveDistortion);

                //Convert direction and _ImpactOrigin to model space for later trig magic.
                float4 l_ImpactOrigin = mul(unity_WorldToObject, _ImpactOrigin);
                float4 l_direction = mul(unity_WorldToObject, direction);

                //Magic
                float impactAxis = l_ImpactOrigin + dot((v.vertex - l_ImpactOrigin), l_direction);

                v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * sin(impactAxis * _Frequency + _ControlTime * _WaveSpeed) * _Amplitude * (1 / dist);
            }

            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
                // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
                o.Metallic = _Metallic;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
                o.Emission = c.rgb * tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).a * _EmissionColor;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
            FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Note: Please let me know if this has any syntax errors; it has been a minute since I've done shader code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the help but I get this eerar           Shader error in 'Custom/JellyShader': cannot implicitly convert from 'const float3' to 'float4' at line 70 (on d3d11)

Comment: @OmaeWAc You're welcome! I changed the line to try and fix that. Let me know how it  goes now.